# Why isn't Entity Framework Core respecting my Select when doing a Join operation?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I am developing an API using .Net Core and Entity Framework Core which communicates with an Azure SQL database.

I identified a performance issue with one of my EF queries involving a left join. Surprisingly it proved to be quicker to have to convert the result of two separate queries to a list and join in C# than simply populate an object with the result of one query. I think I have worked out what is happening but I would like to know why.

***Original code:***

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

string[] values = new[] { val1, val2, val3 };

var qry1 = _logic.GetAllTable1Data();
qry1 = qry1.Include(a => a.Table2);
qry1 = qry1.Include(a => a.Table3);
qry1 = qry1.Where(a => values.Contains(a.Table2.Column));

var select = qry1.Select(a => new { a.Column1, a.Table3.Column2 });

var qry2 = _logic.GetAllTable4Data();

var join = select.GroupJoin(qry2, a => a.Column1, a => a.Column1,
    (a, b) => new { Table1 = a, Table2 = b }).ToList();

sw.Stop();
return sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```

SQL produced:

```
SELECT 
[a].[Column1] AS [Column10], 
...
All 80+ columns from Table1
...
All Columns from Table4
... 
[a.Table3].[Column2]
FROM [Standard_Case] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [Table3] AS [a.Table3] ON [a].[Column1] = [a.Table3].[Column1]
INNER JOIN [Table2] AS [a.Table2] ON [a].[Column] = [a.Table2].[Column]
LEFT JOIN [Table4] AS [a0] ON [a].[Column1] = [a0].[Column1]
WHERE [a.Table2].[Column] IN (val1, val2, val3)
ORDER BY [Column10] 

(execution time 488 ms)
```

Time taken:

```
2.9992557 s
```

***Modified code:***

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

string[] values = new[] { val1, val2, val3 };

var qry1 = _logic.GetAllTable1Data();
qry1 = qry1.Include(a => a.Table2);
qry1 = qry1.Include(a => a.Table3);
qry1 = qry1.Where(a => values.Contains(a.Table2.Column));

var select = qry1.Select(a => new { a.Column1, a.Table3.Column2 }).ToList();

var qry2 = _logic.GetAllTable4Data().ToList();

var join = select.GroupJoin(qry2, a => a.Column1, a => a.Column1,
    (a, b) => new { Table1 = a, Table2 = b }).ToList();

sw.Stop();
return sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```

SQL produced:

```
SELECT 
[a].[Column1], 
[a.Table3].[Column2] 
FROM [Table1] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN [Table3] AS [a.Table3] ON [a].[Column1] = [a.Table3].[Column1]
INNER JOIN [Table2] AS [a.Table2] ON [a].[Column] = [a.Table2].[Column]
WHERE [a.Table2].[Column] IN (val1, val2, val3)

(execution time 8 ms)

SELECT 
...
All Columns from Table4
...
FROM [Table4] AS [s]

(execution time 7 ms)
```

Time taken

```
0.7477659 s
```

I think the reason the original code takes so much longer is that it selects a lot of columns from the database (> 80) that I did not request and do not need (every column from the base table of the query). This results in much more data being pulled back from the query.

Does anyone know why my Select operator is not being respected as it is when I run the queries separately or any other theories about why my first code is so much slower. An `ORDER` operator is also being inserted into the first query - is there a reason why?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. To do more performance troubleshooting, it would be useful to have the query execution plans in both cases. You can generate the query execution plans using SSMS and post a link to the files here in the comment.

Comment: As far as I remember, there were similar issues with earlier versions of EF Core which should have been fixed in the latest version. What EF Core version are you using?

Comment: @EstienneGranet Thanks for the suggestion but it's not the performance of the query that I'm really worried about, it's why thaty specific query is generated by Entity Framework in the first place.

Comment: @IvanStoev Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.1

Comment: Then the answer is simple - no special reason, just imperfect EF Core  query translation at the moment. You know EF Core is still in active development. Query translation is improved with each new version, but as you can see, still far from perfect (or even from EF6).